# Get maximum value of each index between multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

So I have three NumPy arrays, all with 300 elements in them. Is there any way I could create a new array with the greatest value at each index? I'm not sure where to start since I'm not comparing numbers in the same list. I know there is some kind of loop where you start from 0 to the length and you need to initialize an empty array to populate, but I'm not sure how'd you compare the values at each index. Very likely I'm overthinking.

```
Ex.
a = [16,24,52]
b = [22,15,136]
c = [9,2,142]
Output = [22,24,142]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

Since all your arrays have the same lenghts, you can stack them vertically by using [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). Then, use [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) on `axis=0`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([16, 24, 52])
b = np.array([22, 15, 136])
c = np.array([9, 2, 142])

out = np.max(np.vstack((a, b, c)), axis=0)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[ 22  24 142]
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `amax`.

```
np.amax(np.array([a,b,c]), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 22,  24, 142])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow your original idea involving a loop and the initialization of an array, you can use `np.zeros()` followed by `range()` and `max()`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([16, 24, 52])
b = np.array([22, 15, 136])
c = np.array([9, 2, 142])

# initialize array filled with zeros
Output = np.zeros(len(a), dtype=int)

# populate array
for i in range(len(a)):
    Output[i] = max(a[i], b[i], c[i])

print(Output)
```

Output:

```
[ 22  24 142]
```